# 'pip' não é reconhecido como um comando interno ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes

Tags: python, pip

Sabe como resolver este problema tenho o python e o pip instalado quando eu digito pip e eu aperto enter aparece isso:

> 'pip' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
>       ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.

Sabem como resolver?

Dados do sistema operacional: Windows 10 x64

Comment: O diretório `Scripts` do Python está no PATH do Windows?

Comment: a pasta scripts eu tenho a versão do python é 2.7

Comment: Você adicionou ela no PATH do Windows? Pode verificar dando `echo %path%` no terminal.

Comment: onde é o ´´path´´

Answer (score 5):

Segue passo a passo para inserção do caminho da pasta Scripts no Path do windows:

Vá nas propriedades do Sistema e clique em Configurações avançadas:

[image: Painel]

Agora clique em variaveis do sistema:

[image: Var]

Na janela que abrir, procure por path como na imagem e clique em editar ou dê dois cliques sobre Path:

[image: path]

Clique em novo e insira o caminho da sua pasta de scrpits do python:

[image: novo]

É isso. Espero ter ajudado.